# Changing the activation behavior of joomla1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am wondering if i can change the activation behavior after registration in joomla 1.5.
The requirement is such that when a user registers and depending on the group the user belongs the activation code is either sent through email or as sms to the subscriber phone.

If the user is sent an sms the user enters the generated activation code before the account is active.

I need to know how to go about this and what best practice should i adhere to.

I am using rsMembership component for subscription.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have access to an API that will provide the SMS service, but you will basically need to rewrite certain sections of the 'register' task method in the com_users controller. I cannot give you specifics as you have not provided enough details, i.e. how will you determine the group etc?

The basic run down would be:

Registration > Catch it before it sends the email > run an assertion > connect to the API, send the SMS

You would then need to create either another page in the com_users component, or separate to it, that will take the activation code, compare it with the value in the database (you should take the email address too and select the row using that as the key), if the code if correct, set the rows 'blocked' value to 0, or whatever needs to change in order to be seen as an active user, you can then finish up with an activation email if you wish.